# Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized after Twitter API V2 403: Forbidden using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I got the error from the title, with help of stack overflow i change to the API V2 but now i got this error Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
Unauthorized

```
import tweepy


# Authenticate with Twitter API
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''


client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key= consumer_key,consumer_secret= consumer_secret,access_token= access_token,access_token_secret= access_token_secret)

# Search for tweets about the Warriors
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query='', max_results=100)
```

I am expecting to get the data from the query.

Comment: The obvious answer is that the key and/or secret are wrong...

Comment: I replace them a lot of times and keep getting this results

Unauthorized                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f66adcd2f691> in <cell line: 18>()
     16 
     17 # Search for tweets about the Warriors
---> 18 warriors_tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query='#Brooklyn Nets', max_results=100)
     19 
     20

Comment: 2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tweepy/client.py in request(self, method, route, params, json, user_auth)
     96                 raise BadRequest(response)
     97             if response.status_code == 401:
---> 98                 raise Unauthorized(response)
     99             if response.status_code == 403:
    100                 raise Forbidden(response)

Comment: Why would you replace them "a lot of times"?  Don't you know what the correct values should be?  Do they change regularly?